# How to enable and disable two jquery using modenizr.js

Tags: jquery, css, skrollr, animate.css

```
if (Modernizr.touch) {
    skrollr.init().destroy();
} else {   
    var s=skrollr.init({
        forceHeight:false,
        smoothScrolling:false,
    });  
}
```

Above is my jquery code where I have used modernizr touch functionality and disabled skrollr.js. Now what I want to do is enable another jquery and css when the touch event is fired. overall skrollr.js for desktop and another jquery and css animation effects for touch enabled devices. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Modernizr.touch) {
            skrollr.init().destroy();
            otherjs.init();
        } else {   
            var s=skrollr.init({
                forceHeight:false,
                smoothScrolling:false,
            });  

      otherjs.init().destroy();
        }
```

i think this is helpful for you. And you use js whichever you want to work on mobile instead of "otherjs"